# C# WPF Debug start exe from external associated file

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

Trying to debug an application that is opened by opening a text-file associated to open the application being debugged.
Is there a way to start the debug and wait for the application to be called without the "Start external program" start action?

Ultimately I'm trying to get the file information of the text-file that opens the application, so that it can be used in the application as a "saved project" file.

I have a text-file named "myFile.cats", I've associated this file extension to open with my executable solution made by the visual studio application in the debug bin.

I've tried using the StartupEventArgs, but it doesn't come back with anything obviously since it's not being called from an external file. So I don't seem to have a way of testing this to make sure it works...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
using Caliburn.Micro;
using ApplicationWPFUI.ViewModels;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using ApplicationLibrary;

namespace ApplicationWPFUI
{
    public class Bootstrapper : BootstrapperBase
    {
        public Bootstrapper()
        {
            Initialize();
        }
        //myFile.cats File opens this exe and the 'OnStartup' runs, where is the myFile.cats information being passed in?
        protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Args.Count() != 0)
            {
                //Save the startupEventArgs to a variable
                GlobalConfigs.FileList.Files = e.Args.ToList();
            }
            DisplayRootViewFor<MainViewModel>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're going to need to show what you're doing most likely (code-wise), what actually happens (maybe some screenshots) and what you are intending to do.  After reading it a few times, I'm not clear on exactly what you're describing here.  A [mcve] would probably be helpful.

Comment: I am with @gravity on this.  It is a little hard to understand what you are trying to do.  If I understand you correctly, you want to debug some application that is started as a result of some file association trigger through explorer.  What I have done in the past, which may not be the most elegant, is to place a sleep at the entry point of the application.  This gives me a chance to attach a debugger before the sleep finishes with a breakpoint in the area of interest.  If this is what you are asking for ;)

Comment: I've added some code, but I don't think that really explains anymore than I already have. I guess my first question in this, is if the StartupEventArgs contains the information of the file that initialized the file-association of windows, which then opens the C# WPF application? What would help me to figure that out though, is how do I debug starting from launching my application using the 'myFile.cats' file?

Comment: Basically, like how does Photoshop know to open a .psd file? How does it know where that .psd file path and the file name is. This 'file.psd' that is double-clicked on that, in turn, opens that file in photoshop?

Answer (score 2):

I was doing it correctly already, with one slight change that needed to be made.
The information needed for the file that opens the application is in the `GlobalConfigs.FileList.Files = e.Args.ToList();`. But, I only need the first variable in that list.

So calling the following does the trick:

`GlobalConfigs.FileList.Files = e.Args[0].ToString();`

Obviously, the `StartupEventArgs` will not always have information in there, since I'll be calling the application by itself as well as opening it with associated files. So I just wrapped that in an if statement:

```
if (e.Args.Count() != 0) { 
    GlobalConfigs.FileList.File = e.Args[0].ToString();
}
```

And Bobs your uncle.